# Bash treat star character as word in associative array

Tags: bash, shell, unix, escaping, associative-array

I'm trying to do a word count in a file and use every word in the file as key in an associative array. The value should be the occurences of the word.

```
while read line; do
  ((occs["$line"]=${occs[$line]}+1))
done < $predfile
```

Now the problem is that there can be a * (star) in the file and I want to treat this star as a word. However when I want to output the occurences of the words with

```
for i in "${!occs[@]}"
do
  echo "$i : ${occs[$i]}" >> $resultfile
done
```

then bash trys to output ${occs[*]} when it reaches the star and I get "occs[*]: bad array subscript". I could use an if statement to handle this but I want to know if I can fill the array keys with escaped keys.

Comment: Would you mind to add a small sample input that shows the above problem? Notice that: `declare -A occs; i="*"; occs[$i]=100; echo "$i : ${occs[$i]}"` works as expected. So the problem must be somewhere else. Did you declare the associative array?

Comment: yes I did the declare it with declare -A. You can use my code above and create a file which you use as my $predfile above with the following content : something anotherthing * (every word including the * separated by a newline)

Comment: The problem seems to stem from trying to use `*` as in index inside the `((...))` expression. There might be a way to fix this, but I would take it as a sign that `bash` is the wrong language for whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: `bash` itself might not be the best ally for this particular purpose, but you could surely use POSIX' magic set of fantastic things, and solve your problem in a single line: `tr ' ' '\n' < $predfile | sort | uniq -c > $resultfile`.

Comment: thanks for the easier soultion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occurs when you try to assign the array element, not when you use it. `*` and `@` have special meaning as an array subscript, and apparently bash will not let you use those values as a regular array subscript. You have to handle `*` and `@` specially.

Arrays subscripts must be integers.If you want to store arbitrary words as the array key, you need to declare your variable as an associative array.

```
declare -A occs
while read line; do 
    [[ $line = "*" ]] && line=star
    [[ $line = "@" ]] && line=asterisk
    ((occs["$line"]++))
done < <(printf "%s\n" a b c \* \* c b a \* 1 2 3 \@)

for key in "${!occs[@]}"; do 
    printf "%s\t%d\n" "$key" "${occs[$key]}"
done | column -t
```

```
star      3
a         2
b         2
c         2
asterisk  1
1         1
2         1
3         1
```

Comment: yes I could do that I just thougth there was a way to let bash know that I don't mean the special meaning of * but apparently thats not possible